# Dist folder is not generated in shopware 6.4 when i run ./bin/build-storefront.sh

Tags: shopware6

Dist folder is not generated in shopware 6.4 when i run  ./bin/build-storefront.sh in custom plugin

i want to run my custom js execute but dist folder not generated in shopware 6.4 but it not works and if i add separately dist folder and run ./bin/build-storefront.sh it is not working